CORS issue when sending data to backend via Axios in React application

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/submitForm' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My full back-end on GitHub https://github.com/JadhavC07/back-end
and my front-end  https://github.com/JadhavC07/Student-Form
Here's my CORS configuration class in my Spring Boot backend:
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
}

And here's how I'm making the API call in my React component:
import axios from 'axios';

const baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/api";

const sendDataToBackend = (data) => {
    axios
      .post(`${baseURL}/submitForm`, data)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Data sent successfully", response.data);
        // Additional logic
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error sending data to the backend", error);
        // Error handling logic
      });
};

I've configured my backend to allow all origins and methods, including POST, which should theoretically resolve the CORS issue. However, I'm still encountering the error. Any insights on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.
I updated the CORS configuration in my Spring Boot backend to allow all origins and methods, including POST requests. I expected this configuration to resolve the CORS issue and allow my React application to successfully send data to the backend API without encountering the CORS error. However, despite making these changes, the CORS error persisted, and I'm still unable to send data to the backend.

I've configured my backend to allow all origins and methods, including POST, which should theoretically resolve the CORS issue theoretically ... assuming you did it right, no point in showing front end code for a CORS issue, since CORS is not controlled in the front end at all

So there is problem in my browser then  , I'm using brave Browser

your browser is the front end ... the issue is most likely the back end ... so, no, it's not the browser

@JaromandaX On the contrary, there is a point in showing the client code in a question. CORS is indeed configured on the server, but that config may not be permissive enough for the client's request. And, for reasons explained elsewhere, the browser's error message may not reveal enough information for the dev to pinpoint the cause of the problem.

So What should I provide ?

This is because I didn't set up a proxy in React.
Please tell us which framework you are using,
whether next js or reactNative,
and we will show you how to set up the proxy accordingly.

I.m using ReactJs for front-end

Hi, welcome. Please take the tour, and read how to answer. Thank you
